# Summing Columns from Joined Tables/Views is causing the values to be doubled

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started working for a company a week ago, and they're having me correct some of their database's issues before I move onto building their newer systems. Their SQL server is tied to and access front end, and when we run the report, I'm finding that the values of certain fields are being doubled. Specifically every field that says 'SUM'.

Now after digging through 36 views to find the offending code, I've found where the error is occurring but I do not really know how to remedy the issue. I've tried to format the code to make it easier to read, but quite frankly, my mind is going numb after staring at page after page of this horrendous mess.

Here is the query, and every column using sum is being duplicated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Date, 
'CDC' AS Name, Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Mod, 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Cell, 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Row, 
BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.Section, 
ISNULL(SUM(BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[Phase A Breaker Amps]), 0) AS [Sum Of Phase A Breaker Amps], 
ISNULL(SUM(BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[Phase B Breaker Amps]), 0) AS [Sum Of Phase B Breaker Amps], 
ISNULL(SUM(BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[Phase C Breaker Amps]), 0) AS [Sum Of Phase C Breaker Amps], 
ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[Phase A Actual Amps]), 2), 0) AS [Sum Of Phase A Actual Amps], 
ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[Phase B Actual Amps]), 2), 0)  AS [Sum Of Phase B Actual Amps], 
ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[Phase C Actual Amps]), 2), 0) AS [Sum Of Phase C Actual Amps], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load], 
ISNULL(Equip.PDU.PDU, N'N/A') AS [PDU # 2], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load], 
ROUND((Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load] +
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load])/ 3.00, 2) AS [Average Total Load], 
ROUND(((Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load])
/ 3 + (Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load] + 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load])
/ 3.00) * Equip.Panel.HighVoltage * 1.732 * 0.99 / 1000.00, 2) AS [Total KW Used], 
Equip.Panel.LowVoltage, Equip.Panel.HighVoltage, Equip.Panel.KWAllotment * 2 AS KWAllotment, 
Equip.Panel.KWRating * 2 AS MaxKW
FROM   Equip.PDU 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
Equip.Panel 
INNER JOIN Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current] 
ON Equip.Panel.Panel = Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2]
LEFT OUTER JOIN BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated 
ON Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1] = BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[New RDC 1] 
ON Equip.PDU.PDUID = Equip.Panel.PDUID
GROUP BY Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Date, Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Mod, 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Row, BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.Section, 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load], 
Equip.PDU.PDU, Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load], 
Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Cell, Equip.Panel.LowVoltage, 
Equip.Panel.HighVoltage, Equip.Panel.KWAllotment, 
Equip.Panel.KWRating
HAVING (Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1] LIKE N'%RDC%') AND 
(Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].[Bus Duct # 1] NOT LIKE N'%SSAB%') AND 
(Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current].Mod = 'D2')
```

Also, if there is an easy way to port this into a stored procedure so I can start to do away from these ridiculous views, then any help is appreciated. The application encompasses nearly 20 interconnected databases, with nearly 350 views in this database alone.

**EDIT** To further clarify, the values in my table for [Phase A Actual Amps] should add up to 173.2, however, they are returning as 346.40. Now when I query only the 'BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated' table, and sum the values, I get the correct datum of 173.3.

Comment: `values of certain fields are being doubled` Duplicates ??? Can you extract only a small part of this code and replicate the problem. Would be nicer to look at. Btw, I really don't envy you. Good luck though.

Comment: better yet, create table and sample rows would be helpful. your call.

Comment: Not duplicates, but rather literally the sum is being doubled, so rather than 2, I get 4. Every single place there is a sum function, it's getting doubled. This only occurs here in this view, and every view that references this view. The actual view that houses the data can be queries by itself and summed, and the correct values are returned.

Comment: That suggests that you might have a `1 to *(Many, 2 in this case) ` mapping among your joined tables. I would suggest you to take a sample values set of your unique ID combination (`Group by` clause) and the query every joined table to identify the culprit.

Comment: @SoulTrain can you further explain on this? How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Sure. I would break your query in chunks. Pick the first 2 table `PDU AND PANEL` and write a query and applying aggregations where ever applicable and then see see your result. If you see an inflated value, use your Group by column values to track what's causing it and then add the next table and so on.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Also, I suspect you are might be using a few of your columns in Group by to just present them in the Select clause and not aggregate around them. I would recommend using MIN/MAX functions for such columns.

Comment: @SoulTrain, I'm entirely new to the enterprise database design world, and have only ever really used them for web based applications. So I'm a bit confused. As far as I can tell, the values that are being summed are only coming from a single view CMSMigrated. I haven't found them present in any other table.

Comment: Ok. try this. Join the first 2 tables and see if your record counts double with respect to PDU. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PDU INNER JOIn PANEL ...`

Comment: @SoulTrain also, the previous developer relied solely on SMMS's built in view designer to create the views. So I know for a fact that nearly every single GROUP BY item is only being used for displaying the values. If you look in the select statement at the top, those are essentially all the values that need to be displayed, and I don't really think they are grouping anything.

Comment: @Also you have a `DISTINCT AND A GROUP BY` in your query, totally not required. The more I look at this query the more worse it looks

Comment: I'm aware, I'm simply trying to break down what's there currently and rewrite it. I'm not entirely sure how to break it apart honestly.

Comment: @SoulTrain How could I remove all the unnecessary junk out of the group by clause? The only thing it appears that I need to group by is `Equip.[cms dump table current].[bus duct # 2] = Equip.Panel.Panel` and `Equip.[cms dump table current].[bus duct # 2] = BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated.[New RDC 1]`

Comment: @SoulTrain I finally figured out what was wrong. After a lot of digging, it turns out there was a combination of problems, primarily that there was in fact duplicate values inside the CMS Dump Table, causing all of the values to be added twice. However, the select distinct should have caught this, but it did not. I separated my aggregation into separate joins, and it corrected the issue. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing, I discovered that my error was in fact, two fold. First of all, the table in which the application is querying contains duplicate values (this will be addressed on the front end). However, even though there was duplicate values, the `SELECT DISTINCT` tag should have caught them. After splitting the aggregation up into separate views, rather than clumping them all together, correct results were obtained.

The correct code is as follows:

```
USE [Bus Duct Report]
SELECT DISTINCT 
    cmsd.[Date],
    'CDC' AS Name,
    cmsd.[Mod],
    cmsd.[Cell],
    cmsd.[Row],
    cmsm.Section,
    cmsm.[Sum Of Phase A Breaker Amps],
    cmsm.[Sum Of Phase B Breaker Amps],
    cmsm.[Sum Of Phase C Breaker Amps],
    cmsm.[Sum Of Phase A Actual Amps],
    cmsm.[Sum Of Phase B Actual Amps],
    cmsm.[Sum Of Phase C Actual Amps],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load],
    ISNULL(pdu.PDU,N'N/A') AS [PDU # 2],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 2],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load],
    cmsd.[Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load],
    ROUND(([Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load] + [Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load] +
        [Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load] + [Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load] +
        [Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load] + [Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load]) / 3.00,2) AS
        [Average Total Load],
    ROUND(([Bus Duct # 1 Phase A Current Load] + [Bus Duct # 1 Phase B Current Load] +
        [Bus Duct # 1 Phase C Current Load] + [Bus Duct # 2 Phase A Current Load] +
        [Bus Duct # 2 Phase B Current Load] + [Bus Duct # 2 Phase C Current Load]) / 3.00
        * pnl.HighVoltage * 1.732 * 00.99 / 1000,2) AS [Total KW Used],
    pnl.LowVoltage,
    pnl.HighVoltage,
    pnl.KWAllotment * 2 AS [KWAllotment],
    pnl.KWRating * 2 AS [MaxKW]
FROM Equip.[CMS Dump Table Current] cmsd
INNER JOIN Equip.Panel pnl ON pnl.Panel = cmsd.[Bus Duct # 2]
JOIN Equip.PDU pdu ON pdu.PDUID = pnl.PDUID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT [New RDC 1], Section,
        ISNULL(SUM([Phase A Breaker Amps]),0) AS [Sum Of Phase A Breaker Amps],
        ISNULL(SUM([Phase B Breaker Amps]),0) AS [Sum Of Phase B Breaker Amps],
        ISNULL(SUM([Phase C Breaker Amps]),0) AS [Sum Of Phase C Breaker Amps],
        ISNULL(SUM([Phase A Actual Amps]),0) AS [Sum Of Phase A Actual Amps],
        ISNULL(SUM([Phase B Actual Amps]),0) AS [Sum Of Phase B Actual Amps],
        ISNULL(SUM([Phase C Actual Amps]),0) AS [Sum Of Phase C Actual Amps]
    FROM BusDuctQueries.CMSMigrated
    GROUP BY [New RDC 1],Section) cmsm
    ON cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1] = cmsm.[New RDC 1]
WHERE   cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1] LIKE N'%RDC%' AND
        cmsd.[Bus Duct # 1] NOT LIKE N'%SSAB%';
```